# Regex to match set of two digits seperated by "."

Tags: regex, pcre

I am trying to match a regex to only select,

two digits followed by optional "." followed by two digits followed by optional "." followed by two digits followed by optional "." followed  by two digits.

For example, if the input data is :

```
12.45.7810
12345678
12.34.56.78
1.234.56.78
12.45.7816
```

Expected  match is:

```
12345678
12.34.56.78
```

I am banging my head to understand why following is wrong:

```
^\d{2}\.*\d{2}\.*\d{2}\.*\d{2}$
```

My understanding I from above regex is as follow:

`^` is start of line
followed by two digits followed by zero or more `.` character,
followed by two digits followed by zero or more `.` character,
followed  by two digits followed by zero or more `.` character,
followed  by two digits
followed by end of line `$`.

However, this is matching lines like `12.45.7816`

Comment: Why are you puzzled? Since `\.*` matches an empty string between `78` and `16`, there is a match in `12.45.7816`. You probably just need `^\d{2}(?:\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}|\d{6})$`, or, shortened, `^\d{2}(?:(?:\.\d{2}){3}|\d{6})$`. Is that what you want? Only match dots if there are dots between *all* digit pairs, or no dots at all?

Comment: yes, this is producing the correct result. I am trying to soak it now in my head :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `\.*` matches an empty string between `78` and `16`, the `12.45.7816` matches.

To only match dots if they are present between all digit pairs, or no dots at all otherwise, you can use

```
^\d{2}(?:(?:\.\d{2}){3}|\d{6})$
```

See [its graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5Cd%7B2%7D(%3F%3A(%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%7B2%7D)%7B3%7D%7C%5Cd%7B6%7D)%24):

[image]

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PGJfYm/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `(?:(?:\.\d{2}){3}|\d{6})` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `(?:\.\d{2}){3}` - three occurrences of a dot followed with two digits
  - `|` - or
  - `\d{6}` - six digits
- `$` - end of string